# Run AJAX Success callback on Error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to cache jQuery ajax data, Globally, using this code:

```
var CACHE={}
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function (event, jxhr, settings) {
    //cache return data
    CACHE[settings.url] = JSON.stringify(jxhr.responseJSON);
});
```

And check this CACHE on every other ajax Send event. if found, abort the call and return the local cache data instead.

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, jxhr, settings) {
    if (CACHE[settings.url]) {
        jxhr.abort();
        jxhr.responseJSON = JSON.parse(CACHE[settings.url]);
        jxhr.status = 200;
        jxhr.statusText = "OK";
        jxhr.readyState = 4;
    }
});
```

Problem is `abort()` will call the `fail()` callback automatically. How do I prevent this and run the `success()` callback?

Comment: Why don't you use the jQuery built-in ajax cache? [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: because it don't work the way I explained